# How to group a bunch of <path>'s

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bunch of paths in my svg that already have id's and classes. how do i group all of the paths together with one class or id? for example, i have these two paths:

```
  <path
     style="font-size:12px;fill:#d0d0d0;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:18.65967751;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-start:none"
     d="m 471.60261,246.44442 29.99111,-0.99619 8.36129,-11.40059 -0.16978,-0.49813 0.58508,-0.68252 h 1.28346 l 2.45362,1.10686 4.6997,5.90324 5.05827,15.71735 1.37784,5.53421 0.11332,0.44279 1.52883,11.1239 0.41524,4.8333 0.26423,10.23838 0.50959,34.0174 -24.17783,3.63415 -6.11526,0.16628 -15.1371,-10.57045 -25.87655,4.99926 -21.25234,27.68986 -9.45597,-12.37832 -7.04008,-9.31609 9.4371,-6.8256 10.94705,-12.63657 v -0.59033 l -1.00034,-1.73412 33.1997,-57.77781"
     id="Monmouth"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  <path
     style="font-size:12px;fill:#d0d0d0;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:18.65967751;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-start:none"
     d="m 435.51515,347.70327 21.25233,-27.68984 25.87652,-4.99933 15.13713,10.57047 6.11526,-0.16629 24.17782,-3.63412 -0.0943,4.40894 1.03809,19.44377 0.32087,5.40515 1.43446,16.45523 3.75592,26.43541 0.94372,8.89177 -0.15103,0.9408 -3.8692,18.09708 -10.32419,35.49318 -4.47322,11.08704 -5.549,5.64493 -22.59243,-9.99858 2.54803,-4.29832 0.60399,-5.81096 -9.7957,-41.48865 -42.78783,-60.04694 -3.56723,-4.74101"
     id="Ocean"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
```

Now how would I be able to use a selector to grab those two together so I can apply javascript to both at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, we will add `pathclass` as a class name, to both paths.

```js
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("path");

for (var i=0; i<list.length;i++){
    list[i].className += " " + "pathclass";
}
```

```html
<path
     style="font-size:12px;fill:#d0d0d0;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:18.65967751;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-start:none"
     d="m 471.60261,246.44442 29.99111,-0.99619 8.36129,-11.40059 -0.16978,-0.49813 0.58508,-0.68252 h 1.28346 l 2.45362,1.10686 4.6997,5.90324 5.05827,15.71735 1.37784,5.53421 0.11332,0.44279 1.52883,11.1239 0.41524,4.8333 0.26423,10.23838 0.50959,34.0174 -24.17783,3.63415 -6.11526,0.16628 -15.1371,-10.57045 -25.87655,4.99926 -21.25234,27.68986 -9.45597,-12.37832 -7.04008,-9.31609 9.4371,-6.8256 10.94705,-12.63657 v -0.59033 l -1.00034,-1.73412 33.1997,-57.77781"
     id="Monmouth"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
<path
     style="font-size:12px;fill:#d0d0d0;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:18.65967751;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-start:none"
     d="m 435.51515,347.70327 21.25233,-27.68984 25.87652,-4.99933 15.13713,10.57047 6.11526,-0.16629 24.17782,-3.63412 -0.0943,4.40894 1.03809,19.44377 0.32087,5.40515 1.43446,16.45523 3.75592,26.43541 0.94372,8.89177 -0.15103,0.9408 -3.8692,18.09708 -10.32419,35.49318 -4.47322,11.08704 -5.549,5.64493 -22.59243,-9.99858 2.54803,-4.29832 0.60399,-5.81096 -9.7957,-41.48865 -42.78783,-60.04694 -3.56723,-4.74101"
     id="Ocean"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
```

First retrieve a NodeList object (similar to array):

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("path");
```

and access as you would with an array: `list[0]` `list[1]` etc. You can't use a forEach because it is not an Array, but can still loop from 0 to `list.length`.

Add a class to the paths with:

```
list[i].className += " " + name
```

IDs are unique, so multiple elements can't have the same ID. Use a class then.

Answer (score 0):

Add same class to all paths you want to select and use jquery to get all of those elements (`$(".abc")`)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<path style="font-size:12px;fill:#d0d0d0;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:18.65967751;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-start:none" d="m 471.60261,246.44442 29.99111,-0.99619 8.36129,-11.40059 -0.16978,-0.49813 0.58508,-0.68252 h 1.28346 l 2.45362,1.10686 4.6997,5.90324 5.05827,15.71735 1.37784,5.53421 0.11332,0.44279 1.52883,11.1239 0.41524,4.8333 0.26423,10.23838 0.50959,34.0174 -24.17783,3.63415 -6.11526,0.16628 -15.1371,-10.57045 -25.87655,4.99926 -21.25234,27.68986 -9.45597,-12.37832 -7.04008,-9.31609 9.4371,-6.8256 10.94705,-12.63657 v -0.59033 l -1.00034,-1.73412 33.1997,-57.77781"
  id="Monmouth" class="abc" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
<path style="font-size:12px;fill:#d0d0d0;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:18.65967751;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;marker-start:none" d="m 435.51515,347.70327 21.25233,-27.68984 25.87652,-4.99933 15.13713,10.57047 6.11526,-0.16629 24.17782,-3.63412 -0.0943,4.40894 1.03809,19.44377 0.32087,5.40515 1.43446,16.45523 3.75592,26.43541 0.94372,8.89177 -0.15103,0.9408 -3.8692,18.09708 -10.32419,35.49318 -4.47322,11.08704 -5.549,5.64493 -22.59243,-9.99858 2.54803,-4.29832 0.60399,-5.81096 -9.7957,-41.48865 -42.78783,-60.04694 -3.56723,-4.74101"
  id="Ocean" class="abc" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />

<script>
  console.log($(".abc"))
</script>
```